# Using a FOR LOOP, how do I display top 3 value in an array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

Using a [`For Loop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), how do I display top 3 value in an array ?

Example my array size is 10 and i have some values listed in the array, I want to use a for loop to pull out the top 3 data and display out in a message box.

```
//Loop to find Highest Qty of Fish Sold
for (int i = 1; i < fish_name.Length; i++)
{
    if (sales_qty[i] > max_value1)
    {
       max_value1 = sales_qty[i];
       max_index1 = i;
    }

    if (sales_qty[max_index1] > max_value2 && sales_qty[i] != max_value1)
    {
        max_value2 = sales_qty[i];
        max_index2 = i;
    }

    if (sales_qty[max_index2] > max_value3 && sales_qty[i] != max_value1 && sales_qty[i] != max_value2)
    {
        max_value3 = sales_qty[i];
        max_index3 = i;
    }
}
```

Should I use `3 max index` in the `loop` ?

*UPDATED*

Currently what i came up with is this :

```
    Array.Sort(sales_qty, fish_name);
    Array.Reverse(sales_qty);
    Array.Reverse(fish_name);
    MessageBox.Show("The Top Three Best Selling Fish is: "+ "\n"
                                                          + "1. "
                                                          + fish_name[0]
                                                          + "-" 
                                                          + sales_qty[0] 
                                                          + "\n"
                                                          + "2. "
                                                          + fish_name[1]
                                                          + "-"
                                                          + sales_qty[1]
                                                          + "\n"
                                                          + "3. "
                                                          + fish_name[2]
                                                          + "-"
                                                          + sales_qty[2]
                                                          );
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use for loop?

Comment: what is your array variable holds?

Comment: Sort the array and pull out items 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Suppose should be: for (int i = 0

Comment: Yes it is mandantory to use a loop. The variable holds an integer and I want to pull out the top 3 int value from the array.

Answer (score 5):

How about something as simple as

```
double[] sales_qty = new double[10] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var result = sales_qty.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3);
```

and if you are interested in the index of the highest values, try

```
double[] sales_qty = new double[10] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var result = sales_qty.Select((x, i) => new
{
    Index = i,
    Value = x
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a second array, while you loop through, you compare all the objects and find the top-3, put them in the second array, and when done, print those in the messagebox.

Or sort the array and pick out the 3 first objects.

Comment: How do i compare the valus in the array ? Can you show me an exmaple please ?

Comment: It really depends on what type of object you got in the array.
Comparision is ususaly done with > and < operators, but looking at the code you supplied, I guess you already know this, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this way:** Using Linq would be ideal and easy

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        int[] array = new int[7] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 8, 6, 4 };
        var topThree = (from i in array 
                        orderby i descending 
                        select i).Take(3);

        foreach (var x in topThree)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: How do i implement this in my code? I don't understand this particular line :foreach (var x in topThree)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as others have said, learn, love and use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx). It will make your life easier.

To answer the question: you seem to have not one but two congruent arrays, one with the quantities sold and one with the fish names. Let's start by combining the data, using the [LINQ Zip operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 var zipped = fish_name.Zip(sales_qty, (Name, Qty) => new {Name, Qty});
```

With this statement, we're combining (zipping) two congruent arrays. Each item in both arrays (Name and Qty) is combined using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to one (anonymous) object with 2 properties.

Now this becomes much easier to work with. For example, you can easily order this list by qty and take the first 3 elements:

```
 var result = zipped.OrderByDescending(item => item.Qty).Take(3);
```

Now you can transform the list to a list of strings, by formatting each item using the [LINQ Select operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 var formattedItems = result.Select((item, index) => 
                string.Format("{0}. {1}-{2}", index, item.Name, item.Qty);
```

Then use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format your message:

```
var message = "The Top Three Best Selling Fish is: " + 
              Environment.NewLine + 
              string.Join(Environment.NewLine, formattedItems);

MessageBox.Show(message);
```